# c9.io wordpress setup issue

Tags: wordpress, cloud9-ide

I've been trying to setup a wordpress site through c9.io but have been experiencing some issues.  I've followed the instructions to the letter(as posted on their website) and I still seem to be having some problems getting it set up.  I did the following steps:

1. Create the wordpress instance through the c9.io dashboard
2. start and create the mysql database using the following command: "mysql-ctl start"
3. Go to the index.php file and run it.
4. Once the index.php file runs, follow the link to setup the wordpress site.

After doing all of those 4 steps and I click the link that is produced from running the index.php file, I get the following message from the browser: "Error establishing a database connection".  I don't know what I'm doing wrong since I've been following the instructions as closely as I possibly could.  The instructions can be found from this link btw: https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/running-wordpress-on-cloud9

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it I would greatly appreciate it.  It seems like everything is working properly until I click on the link produced by index.php.  Once I click on that link I receive the error message.  Please let me know how you guys were able to remedy this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you check whether mysql started properly by typing `mysql-ctl status`? Also, what's your cloud9 username? Is it longer than 16 characters?

Comment: I typed mysql-ctl status and it said the mysql server is running successfully. My cloud9 username is 18 characters long.  Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that your cloud9 username is longer than 16 characters and MySQL usernames [cannot be more than 16 characters long](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/user-names.html), you would have to update your wp-config.php to pass only the first 16 characters. Currently it should say something like:

```
define('DB_USER', getenv('C9_USER'));
```

you can replace `getenv('C9_USER')` with the first 16 characters of your username. This should make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Incase the above answer does not fix this issue for other intrepid searchers.

I found `mysql-ctl status` would allways show the service as stopped `mysql-ctl start` had no effect and `mysql-ctl cli` returned the OP error.

Using `mysql-ctl install` I reinstalled (wiped) the original installation and got a fresh one which worked right off the bat.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: The "mysql-ctl start" solved my issue, somehow it got stopped.